# PeerJS server Just totally doesn't work at all?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I realize that sounds kinda crazy. But really. The 3 steps at the top of the README just really don't actually work at all.

Here's the readme: https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server/blob/master/README.md

Follow those 3 steps to install, run, and see the test message in the browser and... Voila! Nothing happens. Browser shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE message.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You Should Have to Reinstall PeerJS Server. It Must Have Not Installed Correctly

First:

```
npm uninstall -g peer
```

Second:

```
npm install -g peer
```

If This Doesn't Work, Try Reinstalling NodeJS From Your System with Installing the latest Version.

Comment: Thank you but uninstalling/reinstalling doesn't help. I should note that I've asked a few friends to try and they experience the same as me. This is not a one-off. This is happening on every MacOS and Linux environment we've tried it on (haven't tried Windows).

Comment: You Then Must Check Your Node.JS Version and Update It to The Latest or if It doesn't work it may be your operating system version problem. You Can update it. it works best on my MacOS 10.14.6 and on Linux Heroku. I Have also Deployed a PeerJS Server on Heroku And It's Working Very Nice. This Must Help You.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a peerjs-server bug. I filed an issue and the developer has fixed it: https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server/issues/230

Answer (score 0):

Install the Peerjs and Install the peer package globally:

> $ npm install peer -g

Run your existing server  and open up another terminal run the following

> $ peerjs --port 9000

The port can be changed make sure to add the same port number that you have used for the client script file.

```
    const peer = new Peer('someid', {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 9000, 
      path: '/myapp'
    });
```